# Get data from an worker thread into another

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I have a situation where a certain method - onConnect(), of a video-streaming library I've used in an existing project, starts a new thread within AsyncTask thread. I know how to communicate with UI thread but I don't know how to pass data from a worker thread to another worker thread. Specifically I want to pass a string produced in this new thread to the background thread.

```
public class A extends Activity{
      .
      .
      public class B extends AsyncTask<X, Y, Z>{
         .
         . 
         String myUrl;

         os.setOctoshapeSystemListener(new OctoshapeSystemListener() {
                      @Override
                       public void onConnect(String authId) {
                         StreamPlayer sp=os.createSP(channel_url);
                             sp.setListener(new StreamPlayerListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void gotUrl(String url) {
                                        //myUrl=url;
                                   }
                             }
                       }
                }
         } 
         .
         . 
      }
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, do you need to do some background processing (as opposed to simply returning the value to the UI thread) in `B` using the value of `url`?

Comment: @clownba0t sure, intensive background processing. Also not to the UI but the AsyncTask thread.

Answer (score 0):

There is several options: 
1) Android thread communicate between each other by using Handler, Message and Loper. You have to have Handler of another thread so you can post Message to that thread. That second thred has a message queue, maintained by Looper, which dispatch messages. But, AsyncTasks's background thread has no Looper, so you won't be able co communicate from your second thread back to asyncTasks's thread
2) preferable path- use rxJava library. You get rid of AsyncTasks at all and switch between threads very easy.